# What does normalization say about storing data from objects that use a decorator pattern?

Tags: database-design

I am just curious as to what the best practices are for storing the data from objects built using decorator design.  I have a base class and can decorate it with A, B, and/or C, with A B and C having distinctly different properties.  I have read some things and watched some videos on normalization, but am unsure how to apply it to this situation.

The only solutions I can think are:
Having 1 table for the entire thing with null-able properties for all the decorator properties.

Having 4 tables (Base, A, B, C), but put booleans in the base class to keep track of whether or not it has a certain decoration.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normalization says nothing about the Decorator Pattern, as normalization is much older.

Check out Table Inheritance though, which I think is more along the lines of what you're talking about.

http://www.martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/singleTableInheritance.html

http://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/classTableInheritance.html

Comment: Ok, awesome.  This is pretty much what I was looking for.  I think the only 2 solutions I could think of were actually examples of each of those.  Thanks.